Is the Cassandra Java driver compatible with JDK 21?
Is the cassandra java driver 4.17 compatible with jdk 21? We are planning to migrate our servers to java 21 and we are using cassandra client. If this is not supported this is a no go for us.
There are some mixed signals available on provider side. In the compatibility section:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/index.html
It is stated that driver requires Java 8 or higher.
But on the upgrade guide page:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/upgrade_guide/index.html
we have an information that there is beta support for Java17.
I already tried running cassandra java driver 4.17 against jdk 21 and it seems to work. But I would like to know if it is safe to use that configuration on production.

(1) Spring Boot 3.3.3 + JDK 21 , use org.apache.cassandra:java-driver-core:jar:4.18.1 (For some criteria, I use Spring Boot as the base selection criteria. See which versions of Spring Boot are supported by a specific package like mysql , log4j , ....) (2) goto https://start.spring.io/ , select Java 21, right side,  click button ADD DEPENDENCIES, input Cassandra , click button GENERATE, download zip, unzip zip, (3) run mvn dependency:tree , then find Cassandra.

I think the Spring Boot project has at least conducted compatibility testing on the packages and versions they selected. For Spring Boot 3.x, the JDK currently used is at least JDK 17. In other words, JDK version 17 is a relatively safe choice. choose.

The Java driver for Cassandra is compatible with Java 21. We are aware of several enterprises that build new apps on Java 21 as the default.
It's been a year since the testing infrastructure was updated to use Java 17 (JAVA-3042) and I'm not aware of issues reported by developers so we should probably remove the beta flag on it.
For what it's worth, I've logged CASSANDRA-19936 to request using Java 21 in the testing infrastructure. In the meantime, please let the project know if you run into issues with Java 21 so we could investigate. Cheers!
